# What is the base of a Broadleaf Shield?

Tags: magic-items, pathfinder-2e, shield

The [Broadleaf Shield](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=2638) does not say what its *base shield* is.    Based on the *Wood* trait I guess it is a Wooden Shield. Is that right?

The AC is the most important aspect, but it would be nice to know if it can be thrown (Meteor shield), or lets your hand free (Buckler), etc.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to know the base shield (aside from knowing the AC bonus, which admittedly is pretty important)? That might help us construct a helpful answer in the negative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Inconclusive, but likely a buckler

Of note is the Broadleaf's bulk, which is only L. There are currently nine other published specific shields that are of L bulk: five are *bucklers*; one is a *duskwood shield*, a kind of *wooden shield* that is L bulk due to its material; the other three are *steel*, *orichalcum*, and *wooden shields*, which should normally be 1 bulk.
Going off of this precedent, the *broadleaf shield* is probably a *buckler*, but it could also be a particularly light *wooden shield*.

It's unlikely to be a *steel shield* given the theme or a *tower shield* given the bulk difference.

It's also unlikely to be a shield from Treasure Vault. Rage of Elements does reference Treasure Vault, but this only happens a handful of times in the entire book. Moreover, no Treasure Vault shield stands out as being particularly applicable, for comparison Rage of Elements' *tales in timber* references Treasure Vault's *wooden breastplate*.

Comment: +1 spot on. It's 1 bulk, so 5-10lbs:https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=187 and e.g. a Viking round shield, a medium wooden shield, came in at 11-15lbs:https://www.quora.com/What-was-the-diameter-and-weight-of-the-average-Viking-shield, so a small wooden shield fits.

Answer (score 6):

### Technically None is Specified

Virtually all [specific shields](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?Category=28&Subcategory=30) have an explicit mention of their base shield, with the [*jawbreaker shield*](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=645) from an early adventure path and the *broadleaf shield* as the only exceptions. It's likely that both of these were left off in error, and with the addition of 12 base shields in the *Treasure Vault* book it's a bit less clear to resolve than with the original 4 (buckler, wood, steel, tower).

Having the [Wood](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=508) trait unfortunately doesn't mean that it has a wooden shield as a base, just  that the magical item is infused with the elemental magic of wood. It's a good indicator that having a wooden base shield was the intent rather than any of the metal options, particularly in the context of *Rage of Elements* as related to elemental Wood rather than elemental Metal.

No "leaf" [material](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?Category=22) exists to allow replacement of a shield's base material, though there was a bone material later added which allows the replacement of wood or metal and gives options for the *jawbreaker shield's* "bone shield". There is a [leaf weave](https://2e.aonprd.com/Armor.aspx?ID=28) armor, but it describes many interwoven leaves as having the statistics of thin wood (wooden shield) rather than a single enormous tree leaf.

The *broadleaf shield* shares a light Bulk with the typical steel buckler, but a magical leaf could reasonably be lighter and easier to carry than a standard shield made of wood or steel, like a [darkwood shield](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=312). Bulk is highly variable for specific shields compared to their base shields, like the 2 Bulk buckler [*sapling shield*](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=1860).

### What's the AC Bonus/Speed Penalty?

Likely any wooden shield could make sense as a base shield for the *broadleaf shield*, but just the standard with a +2 AC and no speed penalty seems most appropriate without explicit confirmation on alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

### It has no base type

> While you're wielding the shield, you gain resistance to a damage type depending on the shield's color. This resistance doubles while you have the shield raised.

The [Broadleaf Shield](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=2638) is a special shield designed to provide resistances instead of AC, which doesn't match any existing shield. The entry lists no base shield nor any explicit AC bonus when used, so the shield doesn't provide one. Instead you are provided a resistance based on the current season which increases when the shield is raised. You can still [Shield Block](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=839) with it, which would enable you to use its regenerative ability.

Comment: I am pretty sure the absence of a base type is not intentional. We caught many things here that an errata fixed later. But you might be right.